# Select all rows and group relational table even if no result is found

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all the categories and transactions made on a certain period. For that, I have this query:

```
SELECT
    b.category, SUM(a.value) as 'total'

FROM
    transactions a,
    transactions_category b

WHERE a.type = 2
AND YEAR(a.date) = :year
AND MONTH(a.date) = :month
AND a.id_category = b.id

GROUP BY a.id_category
ORDER BY total DESC
```

This is working fine, but it only select the categories that have any transaction associated with it. For example, if I had a category named 'Internet' and in that month there were no transactions related to the 'Internet' then it will not show on that list.

How can I select the sum of the transactions for all categories even when no transaction exists on that month?

The expected result would be something like:

```
category: 'Office', total: 240,00
category: 'Internet', total: 0,00
category: 'Food', total: 580,00
...
```

Comment: Then why do you add this condition `a.type = 2`?

Comment: @andrewnagyeb because there are transactions of type expenses and revenues.

Comment: @celsomtrindade Issue with that is when `a.type` equals `NULL` the row is not returned. Like @MKhalidJunaid explained you need a left join. There is a nice graphic here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-left-join/

Comment: @andrewnagyeb The type is required and can't be null. It must be 1 or 2. But yes, I saw his explanation. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `left` join and move all filters from `where` clause to `on` clasue

```
SELECT
    c.category, SUM(t.value) as 'total'
FROM transactions_category c
LEFT JOIN transactions t 
  ON t.id_category = c.id
  AND t.type = 2
  AND YEAR(t.date) = :year
  AND MONTH(t.date) = :month
GROUP BY c.category
ORDER BY total DESC
```

this way you will always get all rows for left table that is category table

Comment: I had tried with left join but didn't moved the the other conditions using `AND` to the left join, only the ID. Now it's working. Thanks!